# Only one row returns! but expected output for all user

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have three table meals,expense,users! 
i want to calculate every user total expense ,total cost from these tables !! in a single query! 
i faced problem in calculation total cost !!

totalcost=meal rate* total meal per user

(meal rate= sum of all user expense / sum of all users meal)!!

when i rum my below query it returns only one row !!  i have tried  group by  but it gives me wrong output :(  Can anyone help me??

```
 {
    SELECT u.name , 
           ((SUM(tot_expenseamount)/ SUM(tot_noofmeal))*tot_noofmeal) as total_Cost,
           IFNULL(t.tot_expenseamount,0) AS tot_expense_amount ,
           IFNULL(n.tot_noofmeal,0) AS tot_no_of_meal 
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT e.user_id , SUM(e.expenseamount) AS tot_expenseamount 
        FROM expenses e 
        WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND e.expensedate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY e.user_id ) t ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m.user_id , SUM(m.noofmeal) AS tot_noofmeal 
        FROM meals m 
        WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY m.user_id ) n ON n.user_id = u.id 
    ORDER BY u.name
```

[meal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZbUZ.png)

[expense table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8WIC.png)

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm2Dm.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V382B.png)

Comment: Which mysql version are you using? You can execute `SELECT @@version` and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it for you.

If you're using MySQL 8.0.2+:

```
SELECT u.name 
     , (expense.TotalExpenseAmount / SUM(MealCount) OVER ()) * MealsPerUser.MealCount
  FROM users u
 CROSS 
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(e.expenseamount) AS TotalExpenseAmount 
          FROM expenses e 
         WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND e.expensedate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     ) expense
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT m.user_id, SUM(m.noofmeal) AS MealCount 
          FROM meals m 
         WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
         GROUP BY m.user_id
     ) MealsPerUser
    ON MealsPerUser.user_id = u.id 
 ORDER BY u.name
```

If not, it becomes even more convoluted:

```
SELECT u.name 
     , (expense.TotalExpenseAmount / meals.TotalMealCount) * MealsPerUser.MealCount
  FROM users u
 CROSS 
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(e.expenseamount) AS TotalExpenseAmount 
          FROM expenses e 
         WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND e.expensedate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     ) expense
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(m.noofmeal) AS TotalMealCount
          FROM meals m 
         WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     ) meals
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT m.user_id, SUM(m.noofmeal) AS MealCount 
          FROM meals m 
         WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
         GROUP BY m.user_id
     ) MealsPerUser
    ON MealsPerUser.user_id = u.id 
 ORDER BY u.name
```

Comment: but it gives wrong output!! it shows  total cost  always as same as total expense !!

Comment: Look into your calculation for total_cost, you have expense/tot_noofmeal*tot_noofmeal so obviously it's going to equal expense.

Comment: Could you please help me to write the correct sql??

Comment: How would I know what you need? Add some data rows into the question and what the expected output for those rows should be and then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: i have allready edited my question!! i have added my meal,expense,user table structure !! and my expected outpu!!

Comment: I rewrote the query for you.