# it only returns one row. and if i use group by it gives me wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, mysql-error-1064

> i have three tables meals,expenses,users! i want to calculate users
>   meal details for a month! i have tried in many ways i stucked :(
>
> i have tried using group by user.id  but it return all user total cost
>   same as total expense! calculation output fully unexpected.

```
SELECT u.name , 
           ((SUM(tot_expenseamount)/ SUM(tot_noofmeal))*tot_noofmeal) as total_Cost,
           IFNULL(t.tot_expenseamount,0) AS tot_expense_amount ,
           IFNULL(n.tot_noofmeal,0) AS tot_no_of_meal 
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT e.user_id , SUM(e.expenseamount) AS tot_expenseamount 
        FROM expenses e 
        WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND e.expensedate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY e.user_id ) t ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m.user_id , SUM(m.noofmeal) AS tot_noofmeal 
        FROM meals m 
        WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY m.user_id ) n ON n.user_id = u.id 
    GROUPBY u.name 
   ORDER BY u.name
```

i have expected total cost for user!! 
total cost= meal rate* user total meal;
meal rate = sum of total expense / sum of all user total meal

> example :  i have three user x,y,z their april month total meal is
>   10,20,30  and expense is 2000,1000,3000
>
> now total expense= 6000(2000+1000+3000) total meal = 60(10+20+30) meal
>   rate = (6000/60) = 100.00
>
> per user total cost will be  let for x, total cost= 10*100=1000/=

**meal table**

[image: meal table]

**user table**

[image: user table]

**expenses table**

[image: expenses table]

**expected output**

[image: expected output]

Comment: Please don't post tables as images. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: Share the data for user table as well.

Comment: I don't think you need sum or grouping in the outer query; your subqueries take care of all that _(unless you wanted to aggregate over all users)_.

Comment: i want to calculate total cost for all user  ! 
total cost= meal rate* no of meal

 meal rate=  sum all expense / sum of all meal  that i got  from subqueries !

now have to calculate total cost for all user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one row returns! but expected output for all user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569943/only-one-row-returns-but-expected-output-for-all-user)